# how to upload the file in google app with progress bar

Tags: google-app-engine

How to upload the file in Google app by using blob and when I upload the file **same time** I want to show the progress bar? I am using servlets.

Answer (score 3):

There are no server side hooks into the blobstore to check upload status. You could get the progress using client-side technologies. Take a look at [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/index.php) that offers the functionality you are looking for.

Also, for an example on how to use it with App Engine, take a look at @NickJohnson blog posts on *Implementing a dropbox service with the Blobstore API* [Part 2](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-part-2) and [Part 3](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Implementing-a-dropbox-service-with-the-Blobstore-API-part-3-Multiple-upload-support).